# table overflows parent element

Tags: html, css

At the top of [this page](http://festivals.ie/show/172/headline/latitude-festival), there's a HTML table that shows summary information about a festivals. One row of the table shows the URL of the festival's website. If the browser is narrow (e.g. on a mobile phone) and the URL is long, this causes the table to overflow it's parent as show below:

[image]

Ideally, I would like the visible portion of the URL to be truncated if it's too long to be displayed in the space available, so in an attempt to achieve this I added:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the relevant table cell, but this didn't work. I then tried to make the URL wrap over 2 lines with the rule

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

But this also didn't work. How can I prevent this table overflowing it's parent when the URL is lengthy?

Answer (score 2):

`table-layout:fixed` should fix this with some tuning. The reason `overflow:hidden` won't work on the cell itself is because it's not actually being truncated, because the table by default grows to accomodate all its content - iow. there *is* no overflow to hide. By switching the table's layout policy from default automatic to fixed it is actually able to clip its content instead.

Comment: In addition, I would think about using the CSS3 `text-overflow: ellipsis` to show the url is being truncated. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Answer (score 2):

Set

```css
#overview > table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

to make the `<table/>` respecting the `width` while ignoring a possible content overflow and

```css
#overview > table a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

to let the link break the line.